# Prevent ArcGIS saving shapefiles into workspace

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop

How can I stop ArcGIS creating output shapefiles as results of various tools?

I have got a script returning a certain value. However in order to get this value a have to use several functions such as `arcpy.CreateThiessenPolygons_analysis` or `arcpy.Clip_analysis`. These functions (tools) return maps and save them into my workspace. I would like to work with them in the script but I don't want them to be saved into the workspace since I won't need them any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround would be to delete those leftover feature classes/shapefiles from within your script, e.g. with Delete_management.

Comment: Or to use in-memory features inside the script.

Comment: For some processes it is handy to have the output go in to a temporary workspace for the duration of the script.  If everything works, use Delete_management to get rid of them at the end.  But if something fails these temporary files can give a better picture of what was going on when your script failed than you can get from the sometimes cryptic error messages ArcGIS puts out.

Answer (score 3):

You can right-click on the output variable and specify that the variable is [Intermediate](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Deleting_intermediate_data/002w00000039000000/) data.  Intermediate data, *when run from the dialog box or python window*, is automatically deleted.  However, you have to manually delete the data if you run the model from the ModelBuilder window.

Additional Information:

- [A quick tour of managing intermediate data](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_managing_intermediate_data/002w0000000z000000/)

[image]